# How to do multiple joins at same in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have data frame like below, where I need to join two tables and create the expected output as shown below and how can this be done

**df1**

```
Zone    Country

EU1      AT
EU1      BE
EU1      FR
AP2      IN
AP2      NZ
```

**df2**

```
Origin_Zone  Dest_zone  Key
  EU1          EU1        A
  AP2          EU1        B
```

**Expected output**

```
Org       Dest  Key
AT        AT     A
AT        BE     A
AT        FR     A
BE        AT     A
BE        BE     A
BE        FR     A
FR        AT     A
FR        BE     A
FR        FR     A
IN        AT     B
IN        BE     B
IN        FR     B
NZ        AT     B
NZ        BE     B
NZ        FR     B
```

How to create the expected output in pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by both zones, then rename columns and select expected columns by list:

```
df = (df2.merge(df1, left_on='Origin_Zone',right_on='Zone')
         .merge(df1, left_on='Dest_zone',right_on='Zone')
         .rename(columns={'Country_x':'Org','Country_y':'Dest'})
         [['Org','Dest','Key']])
print (df)
   Org Dest Key
0   AT   AT   A
1   AT   BE   A
2   AT   FR   A
3   BE   AT   A
4   BE   BE   A
5   BE   FR   A
6   FR   AT   A
7   FR   BE   A
8   FR   FR   A
9   IN   AT   B
10  IN   BE   B
11  IN   FR   B
12  NZ   AT   B
13  NZ   BE   B
14  NZ   FR   B
```

Comment: You are a Pandas’ superhuman. A collection of your Pandas answers would make the best practical resources available of Pandas library.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel - I dont thinks so, I only code a lot. I think there is many a betters pandas coder like me, but they are obviously too busy.